# A standard deck has 52 cards, how many ways is there to not draw 3 cards from the same suit. (without replacement)

Tags: probability, combinations

I know that you can calculate this by using a complement. That would be (total ways of selecting 3 cards from 52) - (Ways to get 3 cards of the same suit). But i don't know how to calculate the ways of not getting 3 cards from the same suit using combinations.

Comment: You would have to break it down into a sum:  cases where the second card is the same suit as the first, and otherwise.  This is why using the complement is often preferred.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew Chin remarks in comments, if you don't go by complements, you need to use a sum: either all three cards come from different suits, or two cards come from one suit and the third card from another.

It's worth doing the count in two different ways:

- First way: Choose the suits, then choose cards from the suits
- Second way: Pick the cards in order, then divide by $3!$ (to disregard the order of selection)

For the first way, we either choose one suit from which to choose two cards and another suit from which to choose one card, or else we choose three suits from which to choose one card each, which gives

$${4\choose1}{13\choose2}{3\choose1}{13\choose1}+{4\choose3}{13\choose1}^3=4\cdot13^2(18+13)=4\cdot13^2\cdot31$$

For the second way, we pick one card freely, then either a second card from the same suit followed by the third card from any of the other three suits, or else we pick the second card from a different suit than the first and then the third card freely, which gives

$${52\cdot12\cdot39+52\cdot39\cdot50\over3!}=52\cdot13\left(36+150\over6\right)=4\cdot13^3(6+25)=4\cdot13^2\cdot31$$

`We get the same answer either way, of course, but it's interesting that the $31$ comes as a different sum in each. (It's not hard to see why: the two cases that form the sum allow for the three cards to come from either two suits or three in the second case.)